# Changing graph with EventHandler

Tags: java, swing, javafx, graph, event-handling

My program is drawing different graphs whenever user push arrow `DOWN`. I'm using **Enum** for this and I am going through each one and I display chosen type of graph on press of DOWN arrow.

In this moment I have 3 types of graph and whenever I go through all of them back to the first one my program throw **`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = AWT-EventQueue-0`**

```
public class Main extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private static void initAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JavaFX in Swing");
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        Charts charts = new Charts();

        frame.setContentPane(charts);

        frame.setSize(1024, 720); //Size of dispalayed window
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            //java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater
            public void run() {
                initAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }             
}

public class Charts extends JPanel{
    private JFXPanel jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();
    private i = 0;

    public Charts(){
        //show first graph so window won't be empty
        drawLineChart(jfxPanel);

        registerKeyboardAction((ActionEvent e) -> {

            switch(chartParams[i].toString()){
                case "BarChart":
                    drawBarChart(jfxPanel);
                    i++;
                    break;

                case "PieChart":
                    drawPieChart(jfxPanel);
                    i++;
                    break;

                case "LineChart":
                    i = 0;
                    drawLineChart(jfxPanel);
                    break;

                default:
                    i = 0;
                    System.out.println("Wrong Parameters!");
            }
            System.out.println(i+ ", ");
        }, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0), WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);

        add(jfxPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}
```

All the `draw...` methods can be empty.

### Error I am getting

This error I am getting.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = AWT-EventQueue-0
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.checkFxUserThread(Toolkit.java:279)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.checkFxUserThread(QuantumToolkit.java:423)
    at javafx.scene.Parent$2.onProposedChange(Parent.java:367)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.remove(VetoableListDecorator.java:329)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.remove(VetoableListDecorator.java:221)
    at javafx.scene.Parent$1.onChanged(Parent.java:246)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.TrackableObservableList.lambda$new$29(TrackableObservableList.java:45)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:329)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:73)
    at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.fireChange(ObservableListBase.java:233)
    at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.commit(ListChangeBuilder.java:482)
    at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.endChange(ListChangeBuilder.java:541)
    at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.endChange(ObservableListBase.java:205)
    at javafx.collections.ModifiableObservableListBase.addAll(ModifiableObservableListBase.java:102)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.addAll(VetoableListDecorator.java:237)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.addAll(VetoableListDecorator.java:103)
    at javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.<init>(XYChart.java:444)
    at javafx.scene.chart.BarChart.<init>(BarChart.java:154)
    at javafx.scene.chart.BarChart.<init>(BarChart.java:142)
    at cz.test.hibernate.Charts.drawBarChart(Charts.java:210)
    at cz.test.hibernate.Charts.lambda$new$0(Charts.java:73)
    at javax.swing.JComponent$ActionStandin.actionPerformed(JComponent.java:3425)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.notifyAction(SwingUtilities.java:1663)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBinding(JComponent.java:2882)
    at javax.swing.KeyboardManager.fireBinding(KeyboardManager.java:307)
    at javax.swing.KeyboardManager.fireKeyboardAction(KeyboardManager.java:250)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindingsForAllComponents(JComponent.java:2974)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindings(JComponent.java:2966)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2845)
    at javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel.processKeyEvent(JFXPanel.java:497)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6310)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2237)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2295)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1954)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:835)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1103)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:974)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:800)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4760)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2295)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)1, 

    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

And when I use `Platform.runLater()` like this:

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            //java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater
            public void run() {
                initAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
```

this is what happens:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Toolkit not initialized
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(PlatformImpl.java:273)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(PlatformImpl.java:268)
    at javafx.application.Platform.runLater(Platform.java:83)
    at cz.test.hibernate.Main.main(Main.java:109)
```

How can I solve this issue? 
Can this problem be combination of **`JavaFX`** and **`Swing`**?

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: This is not enough information to help you.  The exception you get is because you are manipulating a JavaFX object but on the wrong thread (the AWT thread in this case, while it should be the JavaFX Event Thread).  The stack trace should show you where this is happening.  Often the solution is to use `Platform.runLater()` where you are updating a JavaFX object.  Please include at least the full stack trace and any code that is yours that is part of that stack trace.

Comment: I added full stack trace and also added what happening after using `Platform.runLater()`. Also I don't understand how is this not **minimal reproducible example**??? This code is minimal and contains just part of the code that doesn't work for me. It's smaller replica of main code and it's reproducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so there were more like 2 main mistakes then one. First one is the one that shows in command I wrote about so I am gonna answer it first.

This can be fixed by `Platform.runLater()` as **`@john16384`** mentioned in comment. But this should be used in `class Charts`

```
case "BarChart":
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        drawBarChart(jfxPanel);
    });
    i++;
break;
```

By this it's gonna **repair error** with **FX thread**. But the next error's may appear.

For example if you gonna try to draw `BarChart` you have to initialize `CategoryAxis` and `NumberAxis` in this method **not like me** when I declared them and initialized before. 
Because if you do it that way these `Axis` will expand about 50% more which means your graphs will be 50% smaller.